# Is it possible to change the Time within “Pause until Date” workflows?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a Workflow that runs daily by using "Pause for 1 Day" at the time it was startet. If I start is at 1 P.M. it will forever run at that time until I terminate it.

Is it possible, to change the time inside the workflow? I thought about an additional List where the time is saved. But I can't figute out how to variably set the time of a date. I can only find predefined hours and minutes like in the image below.

Is it possible to change the Time afterwards in a running sharepoint 2013 workflow?

[image: workflow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i could understand you correctly, you want to change the waiting time while the PAUSE is being executed, like cutting short the 1 day of delay while the workflow is waiting?

I can't see how this could be done without some ugly hacking. You could make small pauses in a loop that checks if the time now is greater than or equal the target time in a list.

Getting "the time now" is a whole new issue. You might need to update an item and get the modified date.

Something like:

Stage 1:

- Create an item in a control list using a key that is unique there (maybe the ID of the current item, related to this workflow instance)

Stage 2:

- Update the item in the control list that you have created (using the key that you defined in the previous stage, like the current item ID)
- Get the modified date on the control list item
- Check if the modified date is greater than the target date that you have on your configuration list

  - If it is not:

    - Pause for 30 minutes
    - Go back to the Stage 2

If you really think that you should do this, think again ( :) ) and maybe let us know why do you need that, so we can come up with a better solution maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a core action "Add time to date", which you can use to add any number of months, days, hours and/or minutes to an existing DateTime value.

Here is a workflow I made to send a reminder email out to a specific group every Monday at noon.  I set a variable to the date and time I really want it to start, then start it early, and have it wait until that date and time.  Then it sends out the email reminder, and then adds 7 days exactly and waits again.

[image: screenshot of workflow]